# Translate lambda into sql query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, expression

I want to convert a simple LambdaExpression into sql query. I am trying to do this by using ExpressionTrees like this:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = (person) => person.ID == 5;
```

when where is a constant right node in the expression, I can retrieve data and I am getting dictionary like this:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "ID", 5 } };
```

but when there is a property access in the right node, my code fails, because MemberExpression can not be converted into ConstantExpression. For example, I can not get person ID value from this lambda expression:

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Test",
    Lastname = "Test"
};

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = (p) => p.ID == person.ID;
```

Question: How to retrieve body data from LambdaExpression, when there is property access in right node.

Comment: I'm totally lost with this question.

Comment: I guess this is not possible as property acess would put the person instance in a closure. If you wish to create Expressions like this you need to pass the instance as parameter. If you could specify your question with regards to what exactly you want to achive I will try to be more specific.

Comment: For example in Entity Framework there is `` DbSet<Person> Persons; ``  when I want to get person from this set, I write code like this: `` Persons.Single(p => p.ID == personObj.ID)`` and entity translates it into sql query and sends to database.  In this example entity does not requires "personObj" instance to get the actual ID to translate it. I am trying to do this translation on my own, but I do not know how to get value from personObj.ID to translate it.  thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write down the expression directly I do not think you can use person like this. This is not "selfcontained" and comes from outside. If you wish to write down the expression you need to make person accessable within the expression. From what I understand you are looking for something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Person, bool>> GetPredicate(
    Person person)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "o");
    var propertyInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty(nameof(Person.Name));
    var expression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.GetValue(person)),
        Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(expression, parameter);
}
```